# React native background service crash app

Tags: react-native

I am using a background service so that when app is killed or at background some tasks will perform

```
import BackgroundJob from 'react-native-background-job';

const backgroundJob = {
    jobKey: "myJob",
    job: () => console.log("Running in background")
   };

   BackgroundJob.register(backgroundJob);

   var backgroundSchedule = {
    jobKey: "myJob",
    period: 1000,
    timeout: 1000,
    exact: true
   }

<TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={() => {
                                BackgroundJob.schedule(backgroundSchedule)
                                .then(() => console.log("Success"))
                                .catch(err => console.err(err));
                            }}
                        >
                            <Text>Schedule regular job</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

I am using the above code serice starts but the problem is app crashes when task have to execute. i am nothing execute in this i am just printing console. So anybody provide me clean code that i can run background service in android react native to perform some task on every 1 minute without crashing app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the pure React Native way to do this:

A task is a async function that you register on AppRegistry, similar to registering React applications:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => require('SomeTaskName'));
```

Then, in SomeTaskName.js:

```
module.exports = async (taskData) => {
  // do your background job here
};
```

You can do anything in your task such as network requests, timers and so on, as long as it doesn't touch UI. Once your task completes (i.e. the promise is resolved), React Native will go into "paused" mode (unless there are other tasks running, or there is a foreground app).

If you need to trigger task by pressing TouchableOpacity, you can do:

```
import { AppRegistry, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Task = require('SomeTaskName');

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('SomeTaskName', () => Task);
  }
>
  <Text>Schedule regular job</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

From: https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android.html

Comment: I have to used app registry as i am using class components. so i am very much confused to use these tasks.

Comment: Using this code you can schedule any task you need. Just put on the 'SomeTaskName.js' file. The task can be [eg] a "for", a "api request", "save async storage data", etc.